# E/AndroidRuntime(29668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android

i have problem i try to make crete application android. but when i'm running my application have problem like this

```
11-14 19:36:51.989: W/dalvikvm(29668): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 292: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setPriority (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-14 19:36:51.989: W/dalvikvm(29668): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b019f0)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fuad.traffic/com.fuad.traffic.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.fuad.traffic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    ... 11 more
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6111000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.E(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.S(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.R(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.my(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2158)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-14 19:36:51.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29668):    ... 21 more
```

this my code

in mainactivity.java

```
package com.fuad.traffic;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

//import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
}
```

anf this is for my androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fuad.traffic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.fuad.traffic"
        android:protectionLevel="signature">

    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.fuad.traffic"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA_5aZyzrTpGcKuigTrCZcjK6TZ2MU4Glc"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is for mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.fuad.traffic.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanx for master in stackoveflow, please help me

thanx stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly given in the stack trace. 
The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6111000 but found 0.  **You must have the following declaration within the  element:**
  `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

You might have imported google play services as a library, but not added this line to the manifest.

Comment: the elemet from, 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">

and what you mind from android:value is apikey?? or just it, like your write??

Comment: No. Not api key. Just give it as i wrote. If you have imported google play services properly, it would work.

Comment: i have import like your write but not running agin, still like it, not running and there's eror and the eror still same, wtih first.

Comment: No. This error wont come if you have added correctly. http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html Use this tutorial.